# In java, do I always need a Main class?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I know that I'll need a main method, but can that main method be in a different class other than the Main class?

Comment: The `main` method is `static`, so it doesn't matter which class holds it. In general, however, I wouldn't mind to have a `Main` class which nests the `main` method - this way it's perfectly clear where the starting point is.

Comment: Yes, your main method can be in any class. There are no naming conventions for the class containing the main method

Answer (score 9):

Not all Java applications require a main method.

Java can also be used to create web applications, for instance, which don't require main methods to run.

The answer to your question depends on what exactly you mean. Do you mean a class with the name 'Main'? Then, no, there is no requirement for this at all.

The only requirement that Java has, is that the signature of the method is correct. the main method must:

- be public
- be main
- be static
- have returntype void
- accept an array of Strings as (only) parameter

It's easier to add it in the public class in a file, but not mandatory. The name of the class it is in, is entirely up to you, though many will choose a name like 'Main' or 'Open', simply to more easily find it.

If you want to be able to run your application, by simple double-clicking the .jar file, you'll need to point to the class that contains the main method (to use: your application might contain a lot of main classes, used for internal testing, but only one can be used to start the actual application) in the manifest file: [Manifest files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Prior to Java 7, it was possible to run a desktop application without a main method, by (ab)using an instantiation block, but this was removed as of Java 7, because this is not what the instantiation block was intended for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to define yout main method in a main class. You can place your main method wherever you want, as long the syntax i correct :

```
public static void main (String[] args){
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely don't.

The method itself can be placed whereever you want it to be, there is no limitation.

However, I personally would recommend putting it in a class which at least contains something like "Main", because when others look at your code, and they are not using an IDE which supports jumping to the `main` method, people usually have an easier time finding your starting point.

However, that is just for sake of readability, and as I said, jumping to `main` is/should be usually a widespread supported feature

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Main method is required to run a function although a java class can be without the Main method. Though, it won't run...

Comment: not exactly, unless you assume Java webapps don't work.